# How can I get 11.04 to recognize my USB headset?

Tags: 11.04, sound, usb

I have a USB headset with microphone (Logitech, model number appears to be A-00009) that I can't seem to get Ubuntu (Natty, 32-bit) to recognize. The hardware is an Asus K52F laptop. Following is the output from dmesg when I plug the headset in:

```
[  528.093828] usb 2-1.2: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[  528.165794] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  528.341688] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  528.517601] usb 2-1.2: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[  528.589556] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  528.765457] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  528.941319] usb 2-1.2: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[  529.348970] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 5, error -32
[  529.421096] usb 2-1.2: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
[  529.828719] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 6, error -32
[  529.828884] hub 2-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
```

I've tried this also on 2 other Linux machines: a desktop running Debian Squeeze and a netbook running Oneiric. Same result. I've done a lot of Googling, but most people having issues with USB sound devices appear to have gotten farther than this. Where should I look next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its uncommon that a USB device announces itself and then refuses to communicate, I would say your headset is defect, its an hardware issue.

Please try to use it on the LiveCD to see if you have any further information or ask a friend (or if available) to try on a computer with a different OS. If it fails then there it will be for sure a hardware defect.

Comment: Thanks, I actually forgot that this laptop still dual-boots Windows. Tried it there, and no luck. The documentation seems to indicate that it should work without a driver install, so I'm going to guess at this point that it is indeed bad hardware.